# Problema sobre matemática discreta - C++

Tags: c++

Estou com esse problema para resolver, sobre Princípio da Casa dos Pombos. Porém está com 25% de erro e só possui um exemplo de entrada.

---

> Por algum motivo desconhecido, Rangel só tem um par de meias de cada cor.
>
> Hoje ele está atrasado para ir a faculdade e ainda precisa pegar um par de meias, mas as meias estão todas bagunçadas.
>
> Dado o número de pares de meias na gaveta de Rangel, ele quer saber quantas meias ele precisa pegar, no mínimo, para ter pelo menos um par da mesma cor.
>
> Entrada:
> Cada caso é composto de um único inteiro N (1 ≤ N ≤ 105) que corresponde a quantidade de pares de meias na gaveta.
>
> Saída:
> Você deve imprimir uma linha com um único inteiro que corresponde a quantidade mínima de meias que Rangel precisa pegar.

Exemplo de Entrada: 1

Exemplo de Saída: 2

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N = 0;

    cin >> N;

    if( N == 0 ){
        cout << 0 << endl;
    }else if( N == 1 ){
        cout << (N * 2) << endl;
    }else{
        cout << (N * 2) - 1 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não está a complicar ? Se cada meia tem um par quando pegar pelo menos `N+1` é garantido que tem um par, resumindo o seu código todo a `cout << (N + 1);`

Comment: Obrigado Isac era isso mesmo

Comment: Eu compliquei mesmo a situação

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como mencionei em comentário o problema é mais simples do que estava a imaginar. O Rangel só tem um par de meias de cada cor. Então assumindo que ele tem por exemplo 3 pares de meias, e por isso `N = 3`, temos isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora olhando para esta imagem, quantas meias você tem de tirar para ter a certeza que tem um par ?

A resposta é 4, pois com muito azar se escolher apenas 3 pode ficar com uma de cada cor, mas a quarta certamente irá fazer par com uma que já tem.

Então o código não é mais do que devolver `N + 1` como saida:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int N = 0;
    cin >> N;
    cout << N + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado isac, ficou perfeita sua explicação.

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer Sem problema, estamos cá para ajudar :)

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessário formulas para utilizar o **Princípio da Casa dos Pombos**.

> Veja os exemplos a seguir.

Imagine que eu tenho 3 casas de pombos. Se eu possuo 4 pombos, então certamente em alguma casa haverá mais de um pombo. Se a quantidade de pombos é maior que a quantidade de casas, haverá certamente alguma casa com mais de um pombo. Foi pensando em exemplos como este que o princípio é chamado de **Princípio da Casa dos Pombos**.

Imagine que eu tenho meias pretas, marrons, brancas e cinzas. Determinado dia faltou luz em minha casa e eu preciso retirar a quantidade mínima de meias para garantir que haverá PELO MENOS duas meias da mesma cor. Ora, vamos pensar na pior das hipóteses, ou seja, pense que você é a pessoa mais azarada do mundo.

Há 4 cores possíveis. Portanto, 4 meias não são suficientes, pois eu poderia retirar uma meia preta, uma marrom, uma branca e uma cinza. Mas, na quinta meia não tem como fugir: ela obrigatoriamente deverá repetir alguma das cores citadas. Assim, com 5 meias eu tenho certeza que terei PELO MENOS um par de meias da mesma cor. Pode até ser que eu tenha (por sorte) mais de duas meias da mesma cor, mas PELO MENOS duas eu garanto.

> Na grande maioria dos problemas, você tem que imaginar que você é a pessoa mais azarada do mundo, tem que pensar na pior das hipóteses.

**Vamos a mais um exemplo**.

Em uma gaveta, há 4 meias pretas, 2 meias brancas, 8 meias cinzas. Qual é a quantidade mínima de meias que preciso retirar desta gaveta para garantir que terei pelo menos duas meias de cores diferentes?

Vamos pensar na pior das hipóteses? Ora, se eu estou querendo retirar duas meias de cores diferentes, o azar é pegar várias meias da mesma cor. Como eu sou MUITO AZARADO, eu começo a pegar meias cinzas (porque é a que tem maior quantidade). Sou tão azarado que pego 8 meias cinzas consecutivamente.

Depois que pego 8 meias cinzas, não tem como escapar. A próxima meia tem que ser de outra cor. Portanto, 9 meias é a quantidade mínima de meias para garantir que teremos pelo menos duas meias de cores distintas. Pode até ser que das 9 meias eu tenha mais de duas meias com cores diferentes, mas isso é sorte e não certeza.

**Mais um exemplo.**

Quantas pessoas precisa haver em um auditório para ter certeza (eu disse CERTEZA!!!) de que pelo menos duas delas fazem aniversário no MESMO dia?

Não quero dizer que tenham nascido no mesmo ano, apenas que façam aniversário no mesmo dia.

Antes de escrever a resposta, quero pensar um momento junto com vocês (se é que já não responderam sozinhos). Vejamos: se houver duas pessoas, obviamente não há garantias de que as duas façam aniversário no mesmo dia. O mais provável é que não seja assim. Mas, além de provável (ou não provável), o fato é que estamos procurando CERTEZAS. E havendo duas pessoas no auditório nunca poderíamos ter certeza de que ambas nasceram no mesmo dia.

O mesmo aconteceria se houvesse três pessoas. Ou até dez. Ou cinquenta. Não? Ou cem. Ou duzentas. Ou até trezentas!!! Por quê? Ora, porque embora com trezentas pessoas em um auditório seja provável que haja duas que comemorem seus respectivos aniversários no mesmo dia, ainda não podemos assegurar ou garantir que o que queremos seja certo. É que poderíamos ter o AZAR de que todos tivessem nascido em dias diferentes do ano. Estamos nos aproximando de um ponto interessante na conversa...

Porque, se houvesse 365 pessoas no auditório, ainda não estaríamos em condições de assegurar que duas delas fazem aniversário no mesmo dia.  Poderia acontecer de todas terem nascido em todos os possíveis dias de um ano. Pior ainda: nem mesmo com 366 (por causa dos anos bissextos). Pode ser que justamente as 366 pessoas que há no auditório cubram exatamente todos os possíveis dias de um ano sem repetição.

No entanto, existe um argumento categórico: se houver 367 pessoas no auditório, não há como fugir: pelo menos duas têm de fazer aniversário no mesmo dia.

É claro que não sabemos quais são essas pessoas, nem se há mais de duas que atendem à propriedade pedida. Pode ser que haja mais... muito mais, mas isso não nos interessa. A garantia é que, com 367 pessoas, resolvemos o problema.

[**fonte**](https://www.pontodosconcursos.com.br/artigo/13694/guilherme-neves/o-principio-da-casa-dos-pombos-fgv)

Comment: Obrigado Leo pela explicação!